# WebDriver en Python con Pycharm no funciona

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, debian, pycharm

Estos son los imports:

> Actualize a la ultima version de Selenium

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import datetime
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
```

Y aca el programa que utiliza el driver:

```
 def mifuncion():

#driver.get("https://prenotaonline.esteri.it/login.aspx?cidsede=100064&returnUrl=%2f%2f")
driver.find_element_by_id("BtnLogin").click()
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("UserName")
sbox.send_keys("federicoacosta96@hotmail.com")
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("Password")
sbox.send_keys("Fede1996")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("BtnConfermaL").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_repFunzioni_ctl00_btnMenuItem").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rpServizi_ctl01_btnNomeServizio").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rpServizi_ctl01_btnNomeServizio").click()
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_datiAddizionali1_mycontrol1")
sbox.send_keys("1140488699")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_datiAddizionali1_btnContinua").click()
```

Y estos son los errores que me tira, luego de haber actulizado Debian:

```
 /usr/bin/python2.7 
/home/educacion/PycharmProjects/untitled/mimi/buenosaires.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/educacion/PycharmProjects/untitled/mimi/buenosaires.py", 
line 67, in <module>
 mifuncion()
 File 
 "/home/educacion/PycharmProjects/untitled/mimi/buenosaires.py", 
 line 29, in mifuncion    driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_acc_datiAddizionali1_btnContinua").click()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 501, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 308, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (596, 768)
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.94)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64)
```

Comment: ¿Podrias compartir parte del codigo html? si ese objeto está dentro de un frame o si hay otra manera de identificar el objeto, podriamos encontrar una solucion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo resolvi.. el problema era que habia actualizado Debian y Chrome, el Webdriver habia quedado desfasado.. Lo actualize (lo descargue de aca [instalador del driver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chromedriver_installer)  e instale).. y funciono todo perfecto..